# AWS DynamoDB scan for unindexed nested attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Does anyone know how to run a scan command on an AWS DynamoDB table,
and get just the items where someNestedElement == 'foo' (this nested element is not indexed)?

Preferably in ruby with the aws-sdk or via the aws console.

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/DynamoDB/Client.html#scan-instance_method

Comment: + use a filter_expression

Answer (score 2):

so indeed as @mircea commented, I succeeded with

```
dynamodb.scan(table_name: "my_table", filter_expression: "some.nested.attribute = :name", expression_attribute_values: { ":name" =>"my_name"} )
```

I had a problem due to using preserved words such as "Data" and "Raw".

Does anyone know how to aggregate and group the items returned by the scan?